# How to get access of other pages inside of index.php by PHP?

Tags: php, apache

I installed PHP and Apache server in my computer.
So inside of "htdocs" I created 2 files(index.php, Contact.php) and a directory(MyClass), after that inside of "MyClass" I created a file(class.php)..

In web browser when I am using the url "http://localhost/MyClass/class.php", the result is : "class.php" sending data to the web browser.

In the same situation is there any way in PHP/Apache to take control of it from the "index.php" ??

Or

I want to be known about all the requests inside of "index.php" which came from web browser, is it possible ????

**But I don't want to use any GET variable like "http://localhost/index.php?class=page2"**..

Apology for my bad English.

Thanks..

Answer (score 2):

You should use `include`, in your case you would use

```
include 'MyClass/class.php';
```

More information about `include` can be found right [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand correctly but a way to not use ?class=page2

is to create a .htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

This will rewrite all requests to non existing files or folders to your index.php
the use $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] to make your navigation.
for example you could use http://localhost/class/page/2

$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] would then be class/page/2

If your website is in a subfolder of htdocs be sure to edit

```
RewriteBase /dir/here/
[...]
RewriteRule . /dir/here/index.php [L]
```

to match it

Answer (score 1):

My problem solved.

Which changes I did they are below :

In "C:\Apache24\conf" need to change file "httpd.conf"

> Just active :

1)

```
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

2)

```
<Directory />
      #AllowOverride none
      AllowOverride All
      Require all denied
   </Directory>
```

3) I am using "Virtual Host", so in "C:\Apache24\conf\extra" need to change file "httpd-vhosts.conf"

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@test.com
    DocumentRoot "E:/TEST"
    <Directory "E:/TEST">
        Allow From All
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
    </Directory>
    ServerName test.com
    ServerAlias www.test.com
    ErrorLog "logs/test.com-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/test.com-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

If you are not using "Virtual Host", then I think you need to add some lines to the "Directory" inside of "httpd.conf" !!

```
<Directory>
    Allow From All
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the PHP `include` function. You can include your MyClass/class.php in you index file. You can then add an htaccess file to restrict files in the MyClass directory from being viewed directly.